# Looping through drop downs using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

I am trying to simulated clicking through multiple options on an online data tool that ends with downloading an excel sheet given your filters.

I am currently using selenium and identifying xpaths.

I am able to get through a single iteration and get a single excel sheet, but I need to do it for every possible permutation of drop down choices. To do by hand is unrealistic, as there are thousands of options.

The website for context: https://data.cms.gov/mapping-medicare-disparities

Does anyone know of a function that can be done in selenium that will work?

My current strategy is to create lists with the xpaths and then try to do a permutation function to get all the combinations. However, this has not worked because the function: b.find_element_by_xpath only allows one xpath at a time.

## examples of lists:

## geography county state/territory

G1 = '//select[@id="geography"]//option[@value="c"]'
G2 = '//select[@id="geography"]//option[@value="s"]'

Geo = [G1, G2]

## creating pool of combinations

import itertools
from itertools import product

for perm in product(Geo, Adjust, Analysis, Domain):
    print(perm)

## actual code to use selenium

```
**from** selenium **import** webdriver
**from** selenium.webdriver.common.keys **import** Keys
b = webdriver.Firefox()
```

## code to click through a popup

```
pop_up = b.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/button')
pop_up.click()
```

## code trying to use xpath to select all options at once

```
b.find_element_by_xpath(('//select[@id="geography"]//option[@value="c"],
'//select[@id="adjust"]//option[@value="1"],'//select[@id="analysis"]
//option[@value="base"],'//select[@id="domain"]//option[@value="d1"]'))
```

error message: InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid type: sequence, expected a string at line 1 column 28

This is because the find_element_by_xpath (I am assuming) will only look at 1 xpath at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your syntax in **code trying to use xpath...** is wrong anyway, but you could just put all the xpaths in a list and loop through it.

```
xpathlist=['//select[@id="geography"]//option[@value="c"]', '//select[@id="adjust"]//option[@value="1"]',.....]

for xp in xpathlist:
    b.find_element_by_xpath(xp)
    #then add code to click or download or whatever
```